# Cauchy criterion involving $\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n$ for a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence and consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. I want to show that the series converges if and only if the following property holds: $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ s.t. \forall n>N, |\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n|<\epsilon$.

(I know that the series is convergent if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy criterion: $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}\  s.t. \forall n\geq m>N, |\sum_{k=m}^n a_n|<\epsilon$.)

To show that if the series converges, then the property above holds, We first suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Then, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim s_n$ where $(s_n)$ is the sequence of partial sums, then by definition of a limit of a sequence, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \ s.t. \forall n>N, |\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n|=|\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} (s_k-s_{n-1})|=|(\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}s_k) - s_{n-1}|<\epsilon$.

However, how do I show the converse? When the convergence of the series is unknown, how can we write down $\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n$?

Comment: This does not make sense. What do you mean by $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}a_n$ when  you do not know before hand that the series is convergent? If you know that $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}a_n$ conveges for some $n$ then the whole series converges simply because the first few terms do not matter for convergence.

Comment: @geetha290krm I agree. I think the problem is flawed.

Comment: This question has appeared earlier (with some flawed answers also). Please let me know if there is a tetxbook containing this fake if and only if statement.